# Google sheets reports "XML cannot be parsed" when using IMPORTXML to get the URLs from a sitemap

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, sitemap

I'm trying to import a sitemap's URLS into a google sheet using:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml","//url/loc")
```

And constantly getting the error:

> "Error: Imported Xml content can not be parsed."

Upon searching and being told to use the old sheets because of a reported bug using ImportXML in the new sheets, and then also trying everything else under the sun, I continue to get this error no matter what.

Comment: Is `http://www.websiteurl.com/sitemap.xml` your actual URL? I doubt it. We need to see the _actual_ URL you are importing from. Same goes for the path expression.

Comment: Well the current sitemap I'm trying to grab is http://www.turn-keytechnologies.com/sitemap.xml, but I've tried multiple different sites and paths and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem this morning. It can be resolved using local-name() which does something magical to ignore the namespace.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.turn-keytechnologies.com/sitemap.xml","//*[local-name() ='url']/*[local-name() ='loc']")
```

Source: http://benellwood.co.uk/2015/06/26/import-a-google-sitemap-xml-file-into-google-sheets/

Answer (score 0):

It an be solved by using

```
=IMPORTDATA("sitemapurl")
```

or if you want it to list them for you:

```
=transpose(split(IMPORTDATA("http://www.turn-keytechnologies.com/sitemap.xml"),">"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Importxml() is notoriously buggy so I created an apps script custom function to solve this.

```
sitemap(sitemapUrl, namespace)
```

The source code is here along with a video for anyone else having issues. https://opensourceseo.org/extract-urls-xml-sitemaps-google-sheets/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Create a 1 file google sheet
2. Column A: Paste URL sitemap
3. Column B: Use `=IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[local-name() ='url']/*[local-name() ='loc']")`

Comment: This uses the same `locale-name()` technique of another answer.   It doesn't seem to add much except pulling the URL out for the sitemap out of a another cell.   Why would you want to do that?